# netlogo: how to position turtles in certain location

Tags: positioning, netlogo

I want to position my turtles in a certain squared location. Why does this code below not work? Netlogo accepts it, but does not compile, saying "can't set turtle variable XCOR to non-number false" It should be pretty simple, but I somewhat can't get around it.

```
crt 50
[
  set size 2

  set xcor xcor >= 81 and xcor <= 90 ;set initial location 
  set ycor ycor >= 81 and ycor <= 90 ;of turtles
  set start-patch patch-here
  pen-down
]
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message pretty much says it all: `set xcor` should be followed by an expression that evaluates to a number. In your code, however, `set xcor` is followed by a boolean expression (i.e., something that evaluates to `true` or `false`): `xcor >= 81 and xcor <= 90`.

In other words, `xcor >= 81 and xcor <= 90` does **not** mean "give me a number between 81 and 90", it is a **question** meaning "is xcor between 81 and 90?" and NetLogo does not know how to `set xcor` to the answer to this question.

If you want NetLogo to give you a number that is in a certain range, you generally need to use the [`random`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random) function. In your case, you could simply do:

```
set xcor 81 + random 10
set ycor 81 + random 10
```

Note that `random` will only give you integers. If you wanted your turtles to be at non-integer coordinates, you could use [`random-float`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-float) instead.

Comment: I'm evidently new to NetLogo, so the language is still new to me. Explanation is very thorough and I'll try to apply the same logic in other cases.